# How to use HashMap to get the data from child of child in Firebase in android?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, firebase-realtime-database

I'm beginner for the Firebase. Could I know how do I retrieve data from child to child from firebase by using HashMap? Could I know how to store ArrayList into HashMap? If I don't use ArrayList, could HashMap replace the ArrayList?

I want to do the function which let the user be able to add the car plate into the firebase-database. I will be using the ArrayList to let the user to add a list of car plate into the system. The code will be shown like that

```
List<String>carPlate=new ArrayList<String>();

 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            phone = Phone.getText().toString();
            ic = IC.getText().toString();
            fullname = FullName.getText().toString();
            carplate = CarPlate.getText().toString();
            carPlate.add(carplate);

           //this data will be successful storing in firebase-database and the results will be the images above
            Account account = new Account(fullname, phone, carPlate, ic);
            if(user!=null) {
                mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).setValue(account);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Register Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(RegisterPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Besides, another class which contain the update function as shown at below:
//THE PROBLEM IS AT HERE
Now I want to update the data. According to this Firebase-database, I try to map.get all the value and then using setter for encapsulation. After that, I remove the data from firebase-database. Then I create new object and then put all the task inside. Finally, I setvalue to firebase-database. After I update the new data, the firebase-database will be automatically push to second level.

[First Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EPyS.jpg)

When I update again, it will push it again

[Second Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv7ZW.jpg)

The second problem is NullException at this line: phoneAcc.set_IC(map.get("_IC"));

The error

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                     at com.google.online_mobile_flexi_parking.ChangeEmailPassword$8$1.onDataChange(ChangeEmailPassword.java:251)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakg.zza(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalg.zzcxk(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalj$1.run(Unknown Source)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my code:

```
private List CarPlate;
         changePhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtPhone = newPhone.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!txtPhone.equals("")) {
                    mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String key=mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).getKey();
                            Account phoneAcc=new Account();
                            Map<String,String>map=(Map)dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            phoneAcc.set_Key(mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).getKey());
                            phoneAcc.set_IC(map.get("_IC"));
                            phoneAcc.set_Phone(txtPhone);
                            phoneAcc.set_FullName(map.get("_FullName"));
                            CarPlate.add(map.get("_CarPlate0"));
                            phoneAcc.set_CarPlate0(CarPlate);

                            //dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();

                            mDatabase.child(mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).getKey()).removeValue();
                            Map<String,Object> task=new HashMap<String,Object>();
                            task.put("_FullName",phoneAcc.get_FullName());
                            task.put("_CarPlate0",phoneAcc.get_CarPlate0());
                            task.put("_Phone",phoneAcc.get_Phone());
                            task.put("_IC",phoneAcc.get_IC());
                            mDatabase.child(phoneAcc.get_Key()).setValue(task);
     Toast.makeText(ChangeEmailPassword.this, "Phone Number is updated, sign in with new password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(ChangeEmailPassword.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                                signOut();
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });


                    } else if (txtPhone.equals("")) {
                        newPhone.setError("Enter phone number");
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: DO you want to use tag (_carPlate)?

Comment: I think no need, that's not my main point

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if still u face any problem

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Agree, I checked thrice, did I entered correct key tag.

Comment: Ok, I try it and see

Comment: @Jane did it worked?

Comment: @rahulkapoor sorry for being late, it cannot work for my code

Comment: @Jane can you edit your question and explain more about your issue. So we can understand properly.

Comment: @rahulkapoor I have posted my question already.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen could you help me to solve the problem also? Thanks

Comment: @rahulkapoor I wish you could help me to solve the current problem because I stuck at here about a few weeks ago. Thank you very much.

Comment: @rahulkapoor I forgot to note down your email, can you please write again?

Answer (score 2):

Create a method to pull data and pass tag from outside, but must note that tag should be on root node.

```
public void fetchData(@NonNull String tag) {
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(tag);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
               Log.d("Value is", value);
         }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Call this method from your activity like this -

```
fetchData("_CarPlate");
```

Comment: I will send email to you if I have problems. Therefore, do you understand my questions?